# Share context with included template django

Tags: django, templates, inheritance, include

Is it possible to share context with an included template in django ? For instance, let's say that we have :

```
base.html 

<html>
    <head>...<head>
    <body>
        {% block content %}{% endblock %}
    </body>

mypage.html

{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}
    Hi this is my template ! 
    {% include 'my_fragment.html' %}
{% endblock %}


my_fragment.html

<div> I want to use the context here ! </div>
```

And my view is calling the template `mypage.html`. I can't call make `my_fragment.html` extends `mypage.html` because it's just a small part of my page. How can I do it without sending all parameters of my view with :

```
{% include 'my_fragment.html' with somevar=myvar %}
```

Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe it's included by default. [Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/templates/builtins/#include)

> An included template is rendered within the context of the template that includes it.

Comment: You're right, I missed that point. I always used `with` when including parameters. 
Thank you, my code will be cleaner now !